# Odoo how to show detail table and in each cell select an option from a many2one field?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I explain how it should work: there must be a view where I can register the available schedule so that the students can enroll.
The problem is that every day of the week students can receive classes in different classrooms.
For example, Monday in classroom A, Tuesday in classroom B, etc.
I thought about creating a table as a master and another as a detail, and then put on detail the day of the week and a many2one field to choose the classroom.
But I have not succeeded, perhaps it is a logical error. If someone can guide me, I would really appreciate it.

> Here code

**Model of the master table(called Schedule)**

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    _name = 'module_name.schedule'
    _rec_name = 'id'

    hi_id_niv_p = fields.Many2one('module_name.level',
                                  string="English level", required=True)  # fk
    .......
    .......
    # falta !!! <- el detalle
    # pruebas
    x_classroom = fields.Many2many(
        'module_name.detail_schedule')
```

**Model of detail table(called )**

```
class DetailSchedule(models.Model):
    _name = 'module_name.detail_schedule'
    # _rec_name = 'id'

    # the next field is to save id of Schedule
    dhi_id_hor_p = fields.Integer()
    # day of the week
    dhi_dia = fields.Selection([('1', 'Monday'), ('2', 'Tuesday'), (
        '3', 'Wednesday'), ('4', 'Thursday'), ('5', 'Friday'), ('6', 'Saturday')], "Day")
    # classroom
    dhi_id_amb_p = fields.Many2one(
       'module_name.classroom', string="Classroom", required=True)
```

**VIEW**

```
 <!--Horario Idiomas Form -->

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="schedule_form_view">
   <field name="name">schedule.form</field>
   <field name="model">module_name.schedule</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form>
        <sheet>
          <group>
          <field name="id" />
            <field name="hi_id_niv_p" options="{'no_create':True,'no_open':True}"/>
            <field name="hi_id_cur_p" options="{'no_create':True,'no_open':True}"/>
            .....
          </group>
          <group>
            <notebook>
              <page name="english_classroom" string="Classroom">
                <!-- Schedule detail -->
                <!--
Here I want to show a table with columns that represent the days of the week, and in each cell you can display the classrooms 
-->
                <div>
                  <field name="x_classroom">
                    <tree editable="bottom" >
                      <field name="dhi_dia" /> <!-- here day of the week -->
                      <field name="dhi_id_amb_p" /> <!-- classroom -->

                    </tree>
                  </field>
                </div>
              </page>
            </notebook>
          </group>
        </sheet>
      </form>
    </field>
  </record>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, why you think you have not succeeded?

Comment: This is all your configuration part.Now you need to create methods that create shcedule on time, Let's say today is the monday then you need to create schedule with automatic classroom select as day of week. As i understand you need to dynamically schedule cources , so all you need is one cron, create and call you pyhton function to create schedule of course dynamically(By day).

Comment: @Kenly thanks for answer me. When I go to my many2many field and click on add item, the seach view appears showing me details of other schedules, what I want is that when I click on add item, a wizard will appear to create a new detail. How can I do it?

Comment: @Saumilgauswami Thanks for your help. I will investigate more about cron.

Comment: Add domain in your one2many field like :- [('id', '<', 0)].  So It's simple domain to not showing any records in the search as you desire and now only thing you can  do is create schedule.

Comment: If you don't need the search option and if the schedule details are related to one schedule only (schedule details have an Integer field to hold the id of the schedule), `x_classroom` field should be of type `One2many` (in this case, `dhi_id_hor_p` should be a Many2one field referencing the schedule model).